# How to run custom clean-up code to prevent JVM from throwing OutOfMemory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

**Case**:

- I have a collection of items with individual Time-To-Live setting for each item.
- Items are removed from this collection only when expired (so it's not a SoftReference-type-thing)
- Cleanup is performed by separate thread that runs every N minutes.
- In some cases it might end up with so many expired items that it might cause OutOfMemoryError.

**Question**: How do I react on possible OutOfMemoryError and run clean-up procedure immediately to possibly prevent it?

Comment: Why don’t you remove them right when they expire?

Comment: A [Caffeine Cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction) may do the expiration the way you need and it also cares for the cleanup. You can add a size or maximum weight limits, so you can prevent the OOM. Basically, you never want to react to an OOM, as it may happen anytime and corrupt your data; prevention is much better.

Comment: @Holger, I'm storing them in ConcurrentHashMap. How do I remove them right away?

Comment: That depends on your expiration logic. Since you said, it’s about individual TTLs, you can simply set up a `ScheduledExecutorService` to remove particular entries right when expired instead of “every N minutes”.

Comment: @Holger, yep, I see, normally this could be an option, but not in my case. I'm trying to minimize memory footprint occupied by sessions. Scheduling tasks will increase memory footprint. Plus I learned not to trust ScheduledExecutorService, it failed me couple times -- it just stopped running things I scheduled.

Comment: Since you have already scheduled an action to cleanup “every N minutes”, there is no fundamental change to cleanup “when the next item expires” instead. The cleaner may remove the expired item, then search for the item that will expire next to determine the new waiting time. The complexity is the same as searching for all expired items after N minutes. The `ScheduledExecutorService` does not spuriously stop tasks. It’s a specified behavior of stopping *when an exception occurred*, so you have to care about potential exceptions in the cleanup task. But you can do it with a single thread too…